# Inverting integral transform $f(s)=\int_0^\infty g(x) \exp(-s g(x)) \mathbb{d}x$

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations, integral-transforms

Suppose our function $f$ is defined in terms of $g$ as follows.

$$f(s)=\int_0^\infty g(x) \exp(-s g(x))  \mathbb{d}x.$$

Are there tools in Mathematica that could let me obtain $g$ given knowledge of $f$, either numerically or symbolically? Assuming $g$ is monotonically decreasing and integrable over $[0,\infty)$

For instance, I'm able to invert the following $f$ using guess-and-check, is there a more enlightened approach?

$$f(s) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi }\ \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{s}\right)}{2 \sqrt{s}} \stackrel{\mathrm{T}}{\longrightarrow}g(x)=\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}.$$

```
With[{p = 2}, 
 Integrate[Exp[-s hi] hi /. hi -> 1/(i + 1)^p, {i, 0, Infinity}]]
```

**Edit** for increasing $g(x)$ like $x+1$, inversion can be done using Laplace transform like below, but this fails for decreasing $g$ like $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ or $\exp(-x)$

```
Assuming[{s > 0, y > 1, t > 0},
 g[x_] = x + 1;
 Print["original g=", g[x]];
 f[s_] = Integrate[g[x] Exp[-s g[x]], {x, 0, Infinity}];
 Print["original f=", f[s]];
 F[t_] = Integrate[f[s], {s, t, Infinity}];
 gi[y_] = Integrate[InverseLaplaceTransform[F[t], t, s], {s, 0, y}];
 Print["recovered g=", SolveValues[gi[z] == x, z] // First]
 ]
```

Motivation: when $g(i)$ is proportional to $i$th eigenvalue of quadratic Q, $f(t)$ is proportional to loss after $t$ steps of  gradient descent on Q. Being able to invert this transform would let me infer shape of $Q$ from the behavior of loss. Wolfram community [post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2362355), related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4242534/998) on math.SE

Comment: Why you are not happy with the answer at math.stackexchange ?

Comment: It requires $g$ to be increasing, so doesn't work for $g(x)=1/(1+x)^2$

Comment: Perhaps there is more than one solution. What happens if you attempt the procedure proposed?

Comment: @mikado The procedure is to call `InverseLaplaceTransform` on $\int_t^\infty f(s)ds$, but this integral seems to be always infinite ... I couldn't find any sample $g$ where Mathematica could solve the integral to get explicit form of $f$, and have resulting $f$ be integrable over $[t,\infty)$

Comment: I posted an answer at math.stackexchange It should be now possible to program it in MA. The solution starts with the `InverseLaplaceTransform[f[s], s, y]`. Next steps, i.e., the determination of its codomain, function inversion,  is better best done manually. I suggest you use MA as an assistant, rather than a black box solver.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the math.stackexchange [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4244315/435814) I have shown that

$$\left\{\theta(y-a)-\theta(y-b)\right\} \left(g^{-1}\right)^\prime(y)\, y=\mathcal{L}^{-1}[f](y)$$
where $g^{-1}$ is the inverse function $g^{-1}(g(x))=x$ and
$$0\le g(0)\equiv a<g(\infty)\equiv b.$$
The sign should be changed if $b<a$. Computing the inverse Laplace transform $\mathcal{L}^{-1}[f]$ in the given example, we have

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erf[Sqrt[s]])/(2 Sqrt[s]), s, t]
```

$$\frac{\theta (t)-\theta (t-1)}{2 \sqrt{t}}.$$

Thus, $a=1$, $b=0$ and
$$\left(g^{-1}\right)^\prime(y)\, y=-\frac1{2 \sqrt{y}}.$$

We can formulate it as a differential equation. We denote $h\equiv g^{-1}$. From the boundary condition $a=1$ we furthermore have $h(a)=0$. Thus

```
DSolveValue[{h'[y] == -1/(2 y Sqrt[y]), h[1] == 0}, h[y], y]
```

$$h(y)=\frac{1-\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{y}}.$$
Finally, we invert this function

```
h = Function[y, (1 - Sqrt[y])/Sqrt[y]]
g= InverseFunction[h]
```

$$g(x)=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}.$$

Comment: thanks. Couldn't find a way to automate finding $a$, $b$ but otherwise works great https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/blog-laplace-transform.nb

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thanks, I was trying to find a way to automate too. Hard...

Comment: Added a bit of background on where this problem arises here -- https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2362355?p_p_auth=sKZux8nF

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Very nice application of classical mathematical methods to contemporary data science.

Comment: What about using something like this to determine $a$ and $b$? `expr = InverseLaplaceTransform[(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erf[Sqrt[s]])/(2 Sqrt[s]),s, t];
domain = FunctionDomain[1/expr /. HeavisideTheta -> UnitStep, t];
Quiet[#[{t, domain}, t], {ArgMin::wksol, ArgMax::wksol}] & /@ {ArgMin, ArgMax}`

Comment: @ChipHurst Consider a monotonically growing $g(x)$. In this case $a<b$. But there could be other functions (decreasing) where $a$ and $b$ change places. This is the case in the worked example. Of course, when starting from an arbitrary $f(s)$ we do not know whether $g$ should be growing or decaying as $x\rightarrow\infty$. It would be nice to find the method to characterize $g$ by looking just at $f$.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach, but probably equivalent to Yarchik's.
It might be slightly easier to work with.
We seek solutions to

```
f[s] == Integrate[g[x] Exp[-s g[x]], {x, 0, Infinity}];
```

Applying an inverse Laplace transform gives

```
eqn = F[t] == 
  Integrate[
   g[x] InverseLaplaceTransform[Exp[-s g[x]], s, t], {x, 0, Infinity}]
(* F[t] == Integrate[DiracDelta[t - g[x]]*g[x], {x, 0, Infinity}] *)
```

Linearising the argument of `DiracDelta`, and substituting `t->g(x)`

```
diffeqn = 
 Assuming[x0 > 0 && g'[x0]^2 > 0, 
    eqn /. u_DiracDelta :> (u /. g[x] -> g[x0] + g'[x0] (x - x0)) /. 
      g[x0] -> t // Refine] /. x0 -> x /. t -> g[x]
(* F[g[x]] == g[x]/Abs[Derivative[1][g][x]] *)
```

If we seek monotonically decreasing solutions, we have

```
diffeqnmonotonic =
 Assuming[g'[x] < 0, Refine[diffeqn]]
(* F[g[x]] == -(g[x]/Derivative[1][g][x]) *)
```

Apply it to the specific case of interest

```
specificcase = 
 F[t_] -> InverseLaplaceTransform[(Sqrt[π] Erf[Sqrt[s]])/(2 Sqrt[
       s]), s, t]
(* F[t_] -> (1 - HeavisideTheta[-1 + t])/(2 Sqrt[t]) *)
```

Note that this is only non-zero for `0<t<1`.
Substituting in to the differential equation

```
specificequation = 
 diffeqnmonotonic /. Assuming[0 < t < 1, Refine[specificcase]]
(* 1/(2 Sqrt[g[x]]) == -(g[x]/Derivative[1][g][x]) *)
```

We can determine that `g(0)=1` from the range of `F(t)`.
`g'(0)=-2` follows immediately from the differential equation, but helps Mathematica pick the correct solution.

```
DSolveValue[specificequation && g[0] == 1 && g'[0] == -2, g[x], x]
(* 1/(1 + x)^2 *)
```

This gives the expected result.

Comment: Can the `g(0)=1` and `g'(0)=-2` parts be automated? Was trying this approach to check if there's a $g$ corresponding to $f(x)=\exp[-x]/x$, or to $f(x)=\max(-\log(x),0)$

Comment: `g[0]` is given by the minimum non-zero value of `F[t]`. The value for `g'[0]` is trivial (if you omit it, Mathematica returns 2 solutions, one obviously spurious).

Comment: I see, thanks. Was wndering if there's a obtain g[0] automatically. Tried `Minimize` with constraints, but that returns unevaluated